# load JQuery with MasterPage C#

Tags: c#, jquery

I using this code below, and its operation is normal but when using with MasterPage its behavior has serious problems thecode not function.

///  script /////

```
$(".cssopen").click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get the A tag
        //var id = $(this).attr('href');
        //alterado
        var id = '.window';

        var body = $("html");
        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight });

        //transition effect        
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow", 0.8);

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top', winH / 2 - $(id).height() / 2);
        $(id).css('left', winW / 2 - $(id).width() / 2);

        //inserido 
        href = $(this).attr("href");
        $('.window').load(href);      

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);

        //$(id).show();
        $(id).show().position({ my: "center", at: "center", of: "html" });
    });

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mask, .window').hide();
    });

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });
```

///////////////  code .aspx //////////////////

```
<div>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtCmd" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/edit.png" href="frmIndexII.aspx" CssClass="cssopen"/>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain those "serious problems" plz..

Comment: Master page will change id of controls so get them by ClientID.

Comment: `its behavior has serious problems` is not enough information to begin to diagnose the problem, and I can't help but point one you haven't actually asked a question here, just (poorly) described a problem. What is your question?

Comment: @Sam - he's referencing the image button by class name, not ID. It *is* a terribly worded question though, with not enough info to even guess :)

Comment: Ah yes, the classic "is broken pls fix" bug. Allow me to look into my crystal ball for a moment here.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure you have posted all the info required but i'm making an educated guess that you are grabbing controls by ID using jQuery and this has broken since introducing a master page.  This is because the master page will change the client side id of the rendered HTML element.

If you are on .net4 and above you can use

```
<asp:SomeControl ClientIdMode="static">
```

And the controls will retain their Id client side.  Alternatively you can add a class to your controls and jQuery them by class rather than ID.

Comment: He's referencing the button by class, not ID.

Comment: Well if you want to nit pick he's referencing something called `$('#mask')` by ID.  The "I added a masterpage and it broke all my jquery selectors" is a common problem for which this the most likely problem./solution based on the info supplied which was a touch vague.

Comment: I'm not nitpicking at all.  The only asp he's shown us is the image button, and he's added the CssClass property to it, and then in his script referenced that class name.  Please don't suggest that you saw all that and then gave this as an answer regardless, because you didn't.

Comment: Without clarification the question is unanswerable and should be placed on hold anyways.

Comment: Oooh dear i don't want to turn this into an argument but I noticed enough to know that this could be the problem and have put up a reasonable solution